# Hierarchies not visible after Deployment

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssas, ssas-tabular

I had several User Defined Hierarchies in my cube table. The hierarchies were basically for all the measures created in that table. I modified and created some measures in that table and after I hit did a build on my local and hot Deploy, all my hierarchies disappeared. I havent processed the cube yet but since I dont even see those in my cubemodel(.bim file), I dont think that bit would matter.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your measures/Hierarchy, hit save (in SSDT) and then deploy your model.  It sounds like you deployed without saving the work you built.